# How to identify general terms using LOD?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, research, linked-data, rdf, ontology

I want to identify `general medical terms` such as `human, patient, hospitals, drugs` using LOD (e.g., wikipedia, dbpedia, wikidata etc.). In other words I am referring to medical terms that are `less granular` as `general terms`.

This give a clue that these terms should reside somewhere in the top of LOD's category hierarchy (more closer to `medicine` category). However, I was unable to find a way of doing it using SPARQL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083424/how-to-get-the-number-of-hops-to-a-category-in-sparqlwrapper-in-dbpedia?noredirect=1#comment96917150_55083424)

Therefore, I thought that it would be great to get expert recoemmendations about the ways I can identify `general terms` using LOD?

I am happy to provide more details/examples if needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no global "LOD hierarhy" of terms. There are various ontologies and knowledge bases, and each has its own idea of the world.

I'd use Wikidata items for the the terms that you've mentioned. They are not in a global hierarchy, they may be lacking links (eg I'm not sure there's any link between `patient` and `hospital`) and you may disagree with whatever hierarchical links exist. But WD is a good source of stable LOD URLs for concepts like that.

If you need very specialized terms, check out portals like http://obofoundry.org. See my report [BigDataGrapes D3.1 - Data Modelling and Linking Components](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1482757) that includes an overview of such portals or ontologies, but in the AgroBio domain (some of those resources are shared with the life sciences and healthcare domains, so they will provide a starting point).

Finally, you could use https://lov.okfn.org to try to locate ontologies. HCLS and AgroBio ontologies are ofte not listed there, but other ontologies are listed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you have misunderstood my question. I do not need to see a link between `patient` and `hospital`. I only mentioned them as examples of `general terms`. :)

Comment: If someone misunderstood your question, perhaps your question isn't clear. You can [edit] your question to improve it, and increase the chance of getting useful answers.  This is more useful than posting explanations or clarifications in the comments.

Comment: @Emi I meant that in a proper health care ontology, there'd be a connection from `patient` to `hospital`, namely some event eg `intervention` that also describes when, what was he treated for, by whom...